# Change entity primary key value and update relationships foreign keys

Tags: postgresql

I have table 'cars':

| car_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| FirsT_123_A | 1 |
| SecoND_123_A | 1 |

another table 'owners':

| id | name | car_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | FirsT_123_A |
| 2 | Pete | SecoND_123_A |

Is it possible to set car_id of 'cars' to lower case and update 'owners' table too?

Results should be:

'cars':

| car_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| first_123_a | 1 |
| second_123_a | 1 |

'owners':

| id | name | car_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | first_123_a |
| 2 | Pete | second_123_a |

Comment: Does your foreign key constraint have `ON UPDATE CASCADE`?

Comment: @Bergi right now it does not. If I add it should it solve the issue I am facing?

Comment: Yes, it would help with the update.

Comment: What *issue* are you facing? Did you try something and got an error message?

Comment: Two issues:
1. How to make all primary keys lower case
2. How to make FK update when I modify PK (this one got answered by you)

Comment: For the first, use an `UPDATE` statement with the [`lower`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function

Answer (score 0):

A way to process such a modification is to use a deferred constraint.

Because you don't give us the complete DDL of your table, I am not able to help you more on this subject.

Take a look over the documentation about [deferred constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-set-constraints.html)...